# Create json with same name elements?

Tags: php

We offer an API for our website with both XML and JSON as returned formats.  Both are coming from a PHP Array.  My JSON return is what's causing me problems.  How do I have same name elements returned instead of [0], [1](https://developer.musixmatch.com/documentation/api-reference/artist-albums-get), etc?  Right now, my returned looks like:

```
{
"rate": {
    "rate_span": "1 Minute",
    "rate_limit": "60",
    "rate_remaining": 59,
    "rate_user": "60"
},
"status": {
    "status_code": 200,
    "status_message": "Request was successful."
},
"favorites": {
    "0": {
        "favorite": {
            "lyric_id": "570"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "favorite": {
            "lyric_id": "3530822107858532003"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "favorite": {
            "lyric_id": "3530822107858535795"
        }
    },
    "favorites_type": "lyrics",
    "favorites_total": 3
}
}
```

I'd rather each favorite be wrapped in it's own "favorite" { ... element and bypass each array being wrapped in [0], [1](https://developer.musixmatch.com/documentation/api-reference/artist-albums-get), [x+1]....  Much like this JSON response: [ARTIST.ALBUMS.GET JSON](https://developer.musixmatch.com/documentation/api-reference/artist-albums-get)

This is the PHP array building the favorites part...

```
$json["favorites"] = array();
$json["favorites"]["favorites_type"] = "lyrics";
$json["favorites"]["favorites_total"] = $userFavorites->recordCount();

foreach($userFavorites as $key => $fav) {
     $song_id = $fav["lyric_id"];
     $json["favorites"][]["favorite"]["lyric_id"] = $song_id;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where the JSON being generated? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: Note that the example you link to is still putting each item into its own sub-object, but where you have `{"0": {...}, "1": {...}}`, it has `[{...}, {...}]` - the *amount* of wrapping is the same, it's just a slightly different *type* of wrapping.

Comment: @IMSoP I follow that.  I guess I don't understand how they are wrapping the data to look like that.

Comment: How would you address them if they have the same names?

Comment: @zerkms seems most JSON results are like the link I provided.  Here is another: http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/artist.html#songs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON has two structures: an "array", which has order but no keys, and an "object" (hash) which has keys but no order. PHP, on the other hand, combines these into one structure, which it calls an "array", which has both keys *and* order. PHP's `json_encode` function therefore has to choose which JSON structure to use for a particular PHP array.

In your data, the PHP array `$json['favourites']` contains both string keys (e.g. `$json["favorites"]["favorites_type"]`) and automatically incremented numeric keys (where you have used `$json["favorites"][]`). Since the string keys can't exist in a JSON array, PHP's `json_encode` will have to encode this as a JSON object, which is why you see the keys `"0":`,`"1":`, etc in the output (those being the same keys you'd see if you used `print_r` on the array, for instance).

If you remove the string keys from that array (moving that data to somewhere else in the structure), then all that is left is the numeric array. Since this is like a JSON array, PHP will output it as such, and you won't see keys in the output.

As I pointed out in a comment, the *amount* of wrapping around each item remains unchanged - the elements do not have "the same names", they simply exist in an ordered structure, rather than an associative one.

Here is [a code demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GV2eVD):

```
$json["favorites"] = array();
$json["favorites"]["favorites_type"] = "lyrics";

// Simlulating entries in loop:
$json["favorites"][] = array('favourite' => array('lyric_id' => 3530822107858532003));
$json["favorites"][] = array('favourite' => array('lyric_id' => 3530822107858535795));

echo "BEFORE:";
echo json_encode($json,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Remove the problematic string key:
unset($json["favorites"]["favorites_type"]);

echo "<br>";

echo "AFTER:";
echo json_encode($json,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
BEFORE:{
    "favorites": {
        "favorites_type": "lyrics",
        "0": {
            "favourite": {
                "lyric_id": 3530822107858532003
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "favourite": {
                "lyric_id": 3530822107858535795
            }
        }
    }
}
AFTER:{
    "favorites": [
        {
            "favourite": {
                "lyric_id": 3530822107858532003
            }
        },
        {
            "favourite": {
                "lyric_id": 3530822107858535795
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wow!  Great answer.  I really appreciate you taking the time to explain what I was doing wrong in addition to the solution.